# Generate client code by using Apache cxf 2.x and Wsimport

Tags: java, soap, cxf, wsimport

am trying to generate Java code from **WSDL** by using

1) **Apache CXF2.x**. It is showing following error..

> WSDLToJava Error: WSI-BP-1.0 R2210 violation: Operation
>   'ProcuraCadastroCallCenter' more than one part bound to body

2)when am using **Wsimport** it is showing following error

> link:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qiS0.png

Please any one suggest to me best solution for Generate client code  and Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Can you post the WSDL you're starting from?

Comment: It looks like your WSDL is not valid

Comment: Thanks for your replay Nenad, It is valid I have checked in SOAP UI ....

Comment: Thanks for your replay @craigcaulfield, I figured out why it is showing that [ERROR] undefined element declaration 's:schema'.. have you any idea about How to resolve schema realated issues..

Comment: Post your WSDL as part of your question and we can have a look at what's wrong.

Comment: Thank for your Interest @craigcaulfield That wsdl is too long But Definitely i will post Screen shot of stack Trace of error

Comment: I have added link for screen shot it contains stack trace of error@craigcaulfield

Comment: Is this possibly a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105706/cxf-2-7-give-common-toolexception-non-unique-body-parts-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105706/cxf-2-7-give-common-toolexception-non-unique-body-parts-error)?

Comment: Thank you @Hintham for your reply is there any solution avaliable with out modify wsdl?

Comment: Not that I know of, check wsimport and cxf documentation, perhaps there a option to handle these violations more relaxed?

Comment: @Hintham Really I have been going through lot of documents realated cxf and wsimport since last two days but i am unable to find solution for these ........